# Delphi - using variables in filters with tClientDataset

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I apologize in advance, but after a bunch of tryings I couldn't find how to do this. I want to apply a filter to a TClientDataSet like:

```
MyDataSet.Filter := ('Field1 = SomeVariable');
```

where

"Field1" is an AutoInc field and

"SomeVariable" is of type Integer

Thanks.

Comment: Replace SomeVariable with its value, make it like filter='field1=10';

Comment: I can't know wich will be the value, this is a user's choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try ?

```
MyDataSet.Filter := 'Field1 = '+ inttostr(SomeVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I didn't realize that I could pass a string argument for comparision to an AutoInc Field. I presume that the propper convertion is used internally.